# wsl.exe in C:/Window/System32 is invisible from cmake COMMAND execution

Tags: cmake, filesystems, wsl-2

i want to launch wsl in cmake custom_command

this is simplfied code

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_OUTPUTS}
    COMMAND wsl.exe -- echo salut from wsl echo
)
```

but it reports **'wsl.exe' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序**

but i'm sure there it is

### Phenomenon

after toss a while, i found there is a weird thing: **C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe is not existed** (but it actully do exists)

this is the output from **cmd.exe**, to minimize meaningless infos, i clip items form wshunix.dll to WsmAgent.dll

```
dir C:\Windows\System32\ws*
...
2019/12/07  17:09            17,560 wshunix.dll
2022/12/19  02:08           169,472 wsl.exe
2023/05/08  09:41           288,256 wslapi.dll
2022/12/19  02:08            87,552 wslconfig.exe
2022/11/18  12:49            32,768 WsmAgent.dll
...
              54 个文件     13,310,380 字节
```

and the test command

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${FFMPEG_CONFIGURE_OUTPUTS}
    COMMAND dir "C:\\Windows\\System32\ws*")
```

and its output

```
...
[build]   2019/12/07  17:09            16,496 wshunix.dll
[build]   2022/11/18  12:49            26,112 WsmAgent.dll
...
43 个文件      9,367,852 字节
```

### Expecting

Q1 i want know why

Q2 i want know some normal way to launch the wsl.exe in cmake custom command

### Stuffs

first feel sorry that i've delete some pal's comment of instruction unconsciously and i dont know how to recover it.

He ask "what did where.exe wsl output"

still cmake command can't see **C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe** ,but after some operation of wsl installation. there is a some kind of 0kb link file
**C:\Users\lull\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wsl.exe** Whose date is **"2022/7/4 22:04"** probably generated by wsl reinstallation.

and cmake command is availiable to see this.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.